# How to use buttons to add or subtract in real time?

Tags: dynamic

I am trying to do the following:

```
a = 0;
Row[{
Button[ "L" , Do[a == a + 1/10, 1], ImageSize -> 60], 
Button["R" , Do[a == a - 1/10, 1], ImageSize -> 60]
}]
Dynamic[a]
```

That is, `a` starts at zero and every time I press those buttons, it adds or subtracts $1/10$ of `a` but it is not working. I tried without declaring `a`, I tried with `Evaluate` but nothing worked. I am using `Dynamic[a]` because I wanted to see in real time if the value of `a` was changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = 0;
Row[{Button["L", a += 1, ImageSize -> 60], 
  Button["R", a += -1, ImageSize -> 60]}]
Dynamic[a]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was curious as to why `a+=1` works and `a==a+1` doesn't work but I noticed  `a=a+1` works... I confused assignment with equality, smh.